# Backup restore mysql from query of single table

Tags: mysql

I have a database with three tables .
I want to create a backup file of some records in the second table :

```
mysqldump --opt --user=${USER} --password=${PASS} --databases ${DATABASE} --where="id = $1" mydb Table2 > FILE.sql
```

the problem is in the restore by using this code .

```
mysql --user=${USER} --password=${PASS}  ${DATABASE} < FILE.sql
```

It deletes the entire database and inserts I only selected records from the previous code .
I wish only the selected records restore without deleting the rest .

Comment: Have you tried running individual queries from FILE.sql one by one?

Comment: When you say it is deleting the entire database - is it actually recreating the tables? Not the database?

Comment: only recreates the second table with the values ​​of the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `[--databases][1]` flag which is used when dumping several databases and should not be used when you want to dump only a single table.

> Dump several databases. Normally, mysqldump treats the first name
>   argument on the command line as a database name and following names as
>   table names. With this option, it treats all name arguments as
>   database names. CREATE DATABASE and USE statements are included in the
>   output before each new database.

Avoid using that argument and for good measure use `--no-create-info` or simply `-t` instead to make sure create table / drop table commands are not in the dump file

Comment: thank you one last thing, I get this error when I run the restore:
Duplicate entry '506' for key 'PRIMARY'
how can I force the restore of all items?

Comment: That's because a record with that primary key already exists in your table. This has in fact been asked and answered here before. One solution is to load into a temporary table and then do an INSERT IGNORE ... SELECT

Comment: ah yes! How did i forget that!

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the `--skip-add-drop-table` option when using mysqldump.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html

This would prevent a drop table entry being added to the sql export.